# How can I split a string with " as delimiter?

Tags: c#, string, readfile

```
try 
{
   settings =System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("config.txt");
   foreach(string setting in settings)
   {                 
      Console.WriteLine( setting.Split('"'  ));
   }
}
```

How can I split the string with my delimiter of `"`. I just want to get that half so I can write my config file. I am a C++ programmer but my current project requires c#.
my return value that I keep on getting is `System.string[]`.
Thank you!

Comment: That is because that is what String.Split returns to you, an array of strings. You need to access the array via the index just like any other array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
settings.Split('\"');
```

You have to escape the quote.

Actually, you don't even have to do that when using `'`.

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "\"test1\"test2";
    var arr = test.Split('"');
    Console.WriteLine (arr);
}
```

Will output

```
test1
test2
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public string[] Split(
    params char[] separator
)
```

Comment: I still get the return value of System.String[]. When my file is not split by a delimiter it gives the line.

Comment: @CompSciStudent: `Split()` will always return a `String` array, that's how it is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just modified it to arr[1] returns the directories  that I want. I wished c# was more like C++ in function use though.

Comment: @CompSciStudent that can be very dangerous: what if a `Split()` operation doesn't return an array with two elements or the value you want is at a different index into the array?

Comment: It will get something based on my config file layout and I have exception handling for it. I am just using it for processing a service since the boss man wants a config file instead of hard coding it.